# How do you get the current url in Twig?

Tags: twig, slim

Inside a twig template I will check

```
if url is: http://example.com/search?keyword=test

{% set pageTitle = query %}  query is test

else

{% set pageTitle = different %}
```

How I can do?

Thank you.

Comment: is not working for me my ask is different (search and try all stackoverflow comments)

Comment: You can get current url from request object. Just pass it to template or make it global with twig extension.

Comment: How? I am newbie to twig :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Slim-Views](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Views) is your friend. Install it via composer and add the **TwigExtension**.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'view' => new \Slim\Views\Twig()
));

$view = $app->view();

$view->parserExtensions = array(
    new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(),
);
```

Now in your template you can access to the current url using:

```
{% if currentUrl() == "http://" ~ domain ~ "/search?keyword=" ~ keyword %}
  {% set pageTitle = query %}
{% else %}
  {% set pageTitle = different %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You can do it using the `~` operator. I improved my answer. [Check this also](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators).

Comment: Thank you what is "http://" ~ website ~ "/search?keyword=" ~ keyword %} ? I should replace domain with website ?

Comment: It's a random name. You can use whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

With Slim v3.8 you can use the following code to expose the path in the **{{ current_path }}** variable:

```php
$container["view"] = function ($container) use ($menu) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig("../templates");
    $basePath = rtrim(str_ireplace("index.php", "", $container["request"]->getUri()->getBasePath()), "/");
    $view->addExtension(new Slim\Views\TwigExtension($container["router"], $basePath));
    $view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal("current_path", $container["request"]->getUri()->getPath());
    $view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal("menu", $menu);
    return $view;
};
```

This follows the approach described in the [Templates](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

To get the current slim url is simple just add a global variable.
For my example i use PHP DI with Simple

```
$twig->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('currentUrl',$c->get('request')->getUri());
```